# Does the usage of Haki affect the user in any way?

Tags: one-piece

We know that Haki is a mysterious power present inside every individual. But only few people are able to awaken and use it. It is very closely related to the willpower of a human being. So the question which arises here is: Does the use of Haki affect the user (physically or mentally) in any way? Does excessive use of Haki take a toll on the user?

- If it is so, how exactly does it affect the user, since Haki isn't something like a physical energy?
- If it isn't so, why don't the Haki users use it all the time? Why do they use it only in specific cases like a battle, or entering enemy territories, etc?

Comment: Interesting question, I think if using haki really drain up their energy, they (haki user) has more than enough energy to sustain it. All of them are really powerfull though.

Comment: on a second thought... maybe they didn't always use haki because if they do that all the time, everyone else will be passed out wherever they go.

Comment: @Shinobu - But that is only with *Haoshoku Haki*. What about the other 2, more common, types of Haki? And also, strong willed people won't be affected by *Haoshoku*. It is only the weak willed ones who get affected by it.

Comment: On other haki, you can always use Kenbunshoku Haki anytime, in skypea, it called mantra, and Enel know what everyone says all the time. while Busoshoku Haki, I don't see any reason why haki user keep using this haki all the time if they can use Kenbunshoku Haki. and yes, Haoshoku Haki only effect weak willed ones, but if you use it all the time in city, would every civilian -which I believe is the weak willed person- be passed out? You don't want to go everywhere and see person passed out all the time do you?

Comment: While Kenbunshoku Haki can be used for the full time, we have not seen anybody other than Enel(even this not for sure) use it extensively. There must be something else to it and using Busoshoku is not bad either. Staying on guard is not a big time IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Does it affect the user (physically or mentally) who is using the Haki in any way?**

- No. I encourage anyone to point out otherwise, but my memory says Haki isn't proven to be exhausting. The conclusion I draw from that is that it's not a **powerup** (i.e. energy drawn from an inner pool of life force/chakra/ki/Namekian-hand-holding).

**Does excessive usage of Haki take a toll on the user?**

- N-- but yes. By nature, excessive activity will generate stress but in accordance with my above answer, *this is just an unlikely result*.

**If it is so, how exactly does it affect the user since Haki isn't something like a physical energy?**

- Haki is akin to concentration to activate, which also makes it task-orientated. Things like Observation are always on, because these are your most basic senses. As long as the user is conscious, there will be a heightened sense of plot convenience—I mean, the ability to detect hostile presences like the "wild beast" in Fishmen Kingdom's Palace. For Armament, this is used only for strengthening, i.e. intensifying the muscles. This is like getting in the zone, turning on that killer instinct, you know what you're about to do and you're gonna do it. So while the user can turn it on at the tip of a hat, there's no point to stay amped up and flexed. That's like walking around with a balled up fist all the time. Haki isn't going anywhere else. Nor is it a get-out-of-Death-Flag card that activates when your enemy has gone too OP or you're a pummeled mess.

  My train of thought: Haki users are just flexing and intensifying their basic characteristics of observation, density, and intimidation. So it is physical energy if you take all the potential energy and turn it into kinetic energy for battle. Since it's not a powerup but more of a concentrated assault mindset, the training makes more sense. It wasn't for the purpose of controlling the uncontrollable, but for developing this state that allows you to demonstrate more strength like knowing how to brace your forehead with hardening for a headbutt or tighten a fist to punch. Not to undersell it, I'm sure the power behind one Haki-shrouded punch will make the difference versus another eventually, but it's never been the deciding climax to a fight.

Answer (score 2):

Haki can be of three type. Conqueror's Haki, Color of Armament, Color of Observation.

Haki is basically used during fights to one up the opponent where some opponents are powerful enough to avoid one's sight or are able to attack faster.So there is no reason why it should be used at every time.Normally one's other senses are enough for fight.

Conqueror's Haki- It cannot be used repeatedly (IMO). It is kind of mentally exhaustive.Also till now there have been only 4 character to be shown using this type. Rayleigh, Luffy , Chinjao and Doflamingo. Of these only Rayleigh can use it to affect selected targets as he did at auction house. Luffy is till now unable to use this to its full potential. Maybe it can be used continuously but luffy can't use it continuous till now.

Color of Observation- It can be used regularly as shown by Enel. He used it to spy on people's conversation. No other character till now have any situation to use it continuously.

Color of Armament- It gives the user an external protective covering to minimize effects of physical attacks.But it does affect the person who is using and also the person on whom it is used. Chinjao used it to counter luffy's punch but his was no match for luffy. so his physical appearance changed. Also Vergo wasn't able to match up to Law. And sanji's leg cracked while attacking Vergo.

Comment: Doflamingo can use the Conqueror's Haki and it was seen when he landed on Punk Hazard and fought against the G5. And Enel could spy on people because of his devil fruit. Color of observation doesn't have that much reach. It was because of DF that its reach was widened. Also, you mentioned, *But it does affect the person who is using* - which may be right, but my question is, how exactly does it affect? Physically? Mentally? I don't understand that.

Comment: about doflamingo i'll update. but enel was born with strong observatio haki. his devil fruit oly helped him to listen what people say. but his large area was due to haki. not of devil fruit. and also how haki affects physically i mentioned some examples. as for mentally i'll see if i can find any.

Comment: Only 4 characters were shown to use conquerors haki?! How could you forget about Ace and Shanks?! Ace-kun used kings haki when he was a kid to safe luffy and Shanks-sama used it just after losing his arm.

Comment: After reading this answer again, actually Rayleigh did not selectively release his Haki, he released it on everyone. He later commented saying to Law and Kid that `they must not be amateurs for taking that blast without any trouble`

Answer (score 1):

Haki requires a certain amount of energy to use. Since Haki refers to the will power of the user, **it uses mainly mental power**. Though we all know that thinking too much for a long period or intensively thinking about things, makes you tired and thus drains your energy.

It seems that **Observation Haki** cannot be turned off and is the odd one of the three in that sense (Eg: Enel knows what everybody says at any time, Aisa and Cobi kept hearing people's, driving them insane at first). Here, it does not costs you energy to turn the ability on, but rather to keep yourself sane hearing so much voices at the same time for all time. It must have been so intense, that it would have been impossible for Whitebeard (due to his illness) to concentrate on everybody around him during the Marineford War, giving Squard the opening to stab him. As mentioned by Crocodile and Marco, he should have been able to sense and avoid that attack.

Releasing **Conqueror's Haki** requires concentration, making it a bad move to use excessively. It would only drain precious energy and wouldn't really effect stronger opponent anyway, so unless you want to intimidate or maintain a badass image like Shanks it wouldn't make much sense to continuously release it.

Finally, **Armanent Haki** requires the most concentration and energy of all forms of Haki. Coating for a long time or coating large surfaces takes a major toll on the mind and body. The user might get used to using such amounts of Haki over a long time, but it would drain their energy pretty rapidly.

> Luffy fully coated his body but was completely worn out after doing so for only 20 minutes. Additionally, using such amounts of Haki took such a huge toll on his body, that Luffy was rendered unable to even stand and needs at least 10 minutes to **regenerate his Haki**, before attempting to do anything else again.
>
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  [image: enter image description here!]

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the fact that [Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki#cite_note-Transfer_Haki-6) originates from an individual's spirit and not their body, even if the user's spirit is transferred into another body, they are still capable of using Haki as if they were in their original body.

This tells me that Haki does not affect users Physical strength as such.

> [Haoshoku_Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki) is the only one that is not used excessively since it might affect the innocent people with weak will power or is not needed once you already knocked down the opponents.
>
> [Kenbunshoku Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Kenbunshoku_Haki) and [Busoshoku_Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Busoshoku_Haki) are used as often as needed to keep on monitoring your opponents activities and defending against their attacks.