# Why are Haki attacks not effective on Marine admirals?

Tags: one-piece

Why are Haki attacks not effective on Marine admirals?

In the Marineford war, we see countless instances where Haki-imbued attacks don't affect Marine admirals. When Marco and Vista attack Sakazuki, he even acknowledges that they are Haki-imbued, but nothing apparently happens:

[image: Marco and Vista attacked Sakazuki]

Another case is when Whitebeard attacks Aokiji:

[image: Whitebeard attacks Aokiji]

What's with the admirals? Their Logia powers don't seem to be easily affected by Haki attacks. I mean we have many instances where Haki has *touched* their body, but still there are many instances where attacks on their body don't result in damage. What's the deal with Marine admirals?

Comment: Sakazuki mentioned that "those two were haki attacks, huh"

Comment: Probably because they're so good that they dont depend on their haki power,they managed to avoid most haki attack, you can see kizaru's blood as he got scratch but when whitebeard attack aokiji, he didn't use haki at all. Haki effect every devil fruit power include logia, you can see at the end of war shank managed to block akainu attack and Ben Beckman threaten kizaru with his gun. It means that admiral still got hurt if someone can attack them with haki

Comment: I am not saying that they can't get hurt . They get hurt , which I have mentioned , but they seem almost invincible even to Haki attacks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are wrong in saying that they weren't affected. They clearly were affected as you can see from the wound on Sakazuki's shoulder. Since both questions have a different answer, I'll reply one by one.

### Whitebeard vs. Kuzan

[image]

From [Kuzan](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuzan#Marineford_Arc) article:

> He then got stabbed by Whitebeard's bisento, to which pirates are seen wondering if Aokiji was stabbed with Haki and if he was dead. Aokiji told them not to spout nonsense before grabbing the bisento and using his Ice Block Partisan attack. All of a sudden, Jozu attacks him and Aokiji is caught off-guard, even bleeding from his mouth.

As you can see, Aokiji was not hit by the Partisan, which was most likely imbued by Haki. This is, because **he opened up a hole, where the partisan would have hit, just before it would hit**. If he hadn't he probably would have been stabbed to the heart. Marine admirals use their power smart and efficiently, but it doesn't mean they can't be harmed. This can be seen just a moment after, when Jozu attacked him with his diamond arm and he was seen bleeding from his mouth.

### Marco and Vista vs. Sakazuki

[image]

From [Busoshoku Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Busoshoku_Haki#Drawbacks) article:

> Devil Fruit users who can use Haki can resist the effects of Haki-imbued attacks, Akainu was able to take Haki-imbued attacks while maintaining his intangibility by extending his Haki through his body in order to nullify his opponents bypass. This however depends on their level of mastery over Haki when compared to their opponent as can be seen when Akainu was in contrast harmed when attacked by Whitebeard's superior Haki and bled.

In chapter 784, it was confirmed that **Haki can be bypassed**. We can see how Doflamingo hits Luffy with a Haki-imbued attack, yet Luffy kept his elasticity during the whole event, bouncing Doflamingo's attack right back. The same must have happened with Sakazuki. It looks like Vista and Marco did hit Sakazuki, and he was affected, because he noticed the attack was different from that of non-Haki users. Though, despite being hit with a Haki-imbued attack, he wasn't harmed and could just reform his neck, because his Haki was superior. I guess Haki is a bit like armor. If the level of an attack is lower than the toughness of an armor, it will be unable to penetrate the armor, and unable to touch the body hiding within the armor.

---

*The answer was updated due to wiki updates. Check the edit revision history for the old answer.*

Comment: The logical explanation would be that Marco and Vista didn't have a Haki which was superior enough to do much damange to Akainu, but Whitebeard on the other hand(being the World's Strongest Man and a Yonko) surely would have had Haki strong enough to make Akainu bleed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only possible answer is that the Marine admirals' Haki is stronger. If their **Kenbunshoku Haki** and **Busoshoku Haki** are stronger, they can easy foresee or block Marco's or Vista's attacks.

And as you can see, Sakazuki got a scratch, so they aren't immortal at all.

I think this just shows **how strong** they really are
(or how weak Marco and Vista are :P).

**Another possibility** is that maybe they don't use Haki. I can't recognize anything that looks similar to when Luffy is using Haki.

Answer (score 0):

The admirals were also using Haki, so it was Sakazuki's Haki vs Marco and Vista's Haki. That's why Akianu was also bleeding, but it did not hurt much because both of them were using Haki.

Comment: They did not combine their powers. So its better if said that it was Marco's haki vs Akainu's Haki and Vista's haki vs Akainu's Haki at the same time. Also commanders Hakis are not to be underestimated and there's no way(as long as I can remember) to combine powers or combine Haki!

Answer (score 0):

I think because Sakazuki's Haki is probably superior to Marco and Vista's Haki, it appears as if he is not affected by their attacks.

To confirm whether the admirals are affected by Haki or not, let's take a look at some cases where a **Haki of same or higher level** is used against the admirals:

1. [Aokiji was thrown away by Marco while attacking Luffy at Marineford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYoTNFcm5dY).
2. [Kizaru vs. Rayleigh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmdWxPzOn9A) (probably same level Haki)
3. [Sakazuki vs. Shanks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6xjr1iqoSM) (same level Haki, or I think Shanks was on the defensive while using it).

So these cases prove that Haki does work on the admirals even though they are Logia users, but the **level of Haki** is what makes the difference!

Comment: Maybe it's just that I haven't followed One Piece, but could you possibly clarify how the second sentence fits into your conclusion?

Comment: It clarifies whether the admirals are affected by Haki at all or no @Maroon,  not how much they are affected, i.e. the main question stands wrong! They are **affected by Haki**.