# How did Aokiji survive Whitebeard's attack; observation Haki or something else?

Tags: one-piece

How did Aokiji survive Whitebeard's attack?

[image: https://youtu.be/iDhECBCf4tU?t=61]

The attack was said to be imbued with Haki. According to Luffy and Rayleigh, Haki attacks should let someone punch even Logia users but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Was it just observation Haki similar to Katakuri? The animation does look very different when you compare Aokiji vs Katakuri.

[image: https://youtu.be/cePAto8rrDw?t=37]

In Katakuri's case, you can clearly see his body making holes. While Aokiji's "dodge" seems to be just his normal Logia devil fruit power. Aokiji is also never shown with the red eyes.

Could this be some sort of awakened Logia?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Haki attacks not effective on Marine admirals?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/why-are-haki-attacks-not-effective-on-marine-admirals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we never got any official confirmation, it is heavily hinted to be similar to Katakuri's technique. Haki punches won't work if there's nothing there to hit.

The animation difference is just due to those scenes being hundreds of episodes apart. The red eyes are also something the anime started doing after the timeskip.