# Why does Luffy use Gear Second so much?

Tags: one-piece

As mentioned [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/how-do-luffys-gear-attacks-work), Gear Second decreases the user's life span. When he first used Gear Second, it was a really important decision to make since it's side effect is so brutal. But after Enies Lobby Arcs he started using it casually. What changed and made Gear Second from a very risky technique to a casual technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main cause is training, and mastering of the technique.

After the timeskip:

> After training with Rayleigh, Luffy is capable of using Gear Second with specific body parts, activating the technique without using the stance we see in Enies Lobby Arc. This way reducing the strain he imposes on his body, making him able to use it withouth the side-effects, it is even stated in the manga that he could use it on his entire body with only the hungry side-effect.

This only explains why he is able to use Gear Second so many times.
The real reason for using this technique so much is because of the formidable opponents he faces. He needs to be able to match or overcome them.

Sources: Manga, http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi/Gear_Second_Techniques

Comment: ...are we sure that's a new side-effect?  ;p

Comment: Now that i think about it i explain why he is abble to use it so many times not why he uses it so many times, well in short we can say because he needs to? seeing his more recent enemies

Comment: @xerido Could you add that into your answer? It seems like it would improve the answer if you would :)